# (Vuejs) add like and remove like does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

`like` toggle does not work correctly

```
    addLike: (state, like) => {
      let posts = state.posts;
      for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        if (posts[i]._id == like.post) {
          if (posts[i].likes.findIndex((el) => el._id === like._id) === -1) {
            posts[i].likes.push(like);
          }
        }

      }
    },

    removeLike: (state, like) => {
      let posts = state.posts;
      
      for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        if (posts[i]._id == like.post) {
          if (posts[i].likes.findIndex((el) => el._id === like._id) === -1) {
            posts[i].likes.splice(posts[i].likes.indexOf(like), 1);
           
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what the issue is without a reproduction in the question, but I see a few problems in `removeLike()`:

- The `if` condition checks whether the `like` does *not* exist (`findIndex` returns `-1` when not found):

  ```js
  if (posts[i].likes.findIndex((el) => el._id === like._id) === -1) {
                                                            ^^^^^^
  ```

  But it should be the opposite:

  ```js
  if (posts[i].likes.findIndex((el) => el._id === like._id) >= 0) {
  ```
- `like` is an object, so `indexOf(like)` will always return `-1`, and `splice(-1, 1)` would remove the *last item* of the array, which may be unexpected if the intended `like` is actually not the last item:

  ```js
  posts[i].likes.splice(posts[i].likes.indexOf(like), 1);
                                               ^^^^
  ```

  To fix that bug, cache the index from `findIndex`, and use it in the subsequent `splice`:

  ```js
  const likeIndex = posts[i].likes.findIndex((el) => el._id === like._id) 
  if (likeIndex >= 0) {
    posts[i].likes.splice(likeIndex, 1);
  }
  ```

Assuming the `like` only pertains to a single `post`, the `for`-loops in both `addLike()` and `removeLike()` should `break` after the relevant `post` is modified:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  if (posts[i]._id == like.post) {
    // add or remove like...

    break;
  }
}
```